Main thread blocked using AVPlayer in SwiftUI
iOS 17.4 - iPhone 14 Pro - Real device
I'm facing an error when I try to implement a simple VideoPlayer view:
Main thread blocked by synchronous property query on not-yet-loaded property (PreferredTransform) for HTTP(S) asset. This could have been a problem if this asset were being read from a slow network.
This is the code I'm using to show the video player:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var player: AVPlayer = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/1760315643142750208/vid/avc1/640x360/-1etorSK7w2g9Nlc.mp4?tag=16")!)

    var body: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: player)
    }
}

I noticed that the bundle initi method of AVPlayer  doesn't trigger this error:
AVPlayer(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video", withExtension: "mp4")!)

I also tried to load metadata's asset with:
try await AVAsset.load(_:)

Before giving It to AVPlayer via AVPlayerItem with no success :/
Does anyone is facing this error too ? Or is It a bug from the SDK ?

First thing to learn about SwiftUI is you shouldn't init classes like AVPlayer as a let in the View struct

Sure @malhal, I should have write @State var player: AVPlayer = ..., I'll correct my initial post

@State var player: AVPlayer? actually
